# filtering out node_id based on their tags?

Tags: python, julia, openstreetmap

I'd like to work with a portion of nodes od an *.osm file. It's looks like this:

```
 <node id="614006085" visible="true" version="5" changeset="87511557" timestamp="2020-07-03T16:17:13Z" user="clay_c" uid="119881" lat="40.7127313" lon="-73.9902088">
  <tag k="description" v="all F,&lt;F&gt; trains"/>
  <tag k="level" v="0"/>
  <tag k="name" v="East Broadway (F)"/>
  <tag k="railway" v="subway_entrance"/>
  <tag k="wheelchair" v="no"/>
 </node>
 <node id="619520020" visible="true" version="3" changeset="86948275" timestamp="2020-06-21T22:49:28Z" user="clay_c" uid="119881" lat="40.7160774" lon="-73.9948416"/>
 <node id="889261487" visible="true" version="3" changeset="22009634" timestamp="2014-04-28T19:52:58Z" user="Rub21_nycbuildings" uid="1781294" lat="40.7139881" lon="-74.0106222"/>
 <node id="889261517" visible="true" version="3" changeset="22009634" timestamp="2014-04-28T19:52:58Z" user="Rub21_nycbuildings" uid="1781294" lat="40.7147476" lon="-74.0112224"/>
 <node id="889261524" visible="true" version="4" changeset="22010391" timestamp="2014-04-28T20:30:28Z" user="Rub21_nycbuildings" uid="1781294" lat="40.7132375" lon="-74.0094599"/>
 <node id="889261540" visible="true" version="3" changeset="65654404" timestamp="2018-12-20T22:41:08Z" user="rbrome" uid="9266455" lat="40.7129150" lon="-74.0088281"/>
```

Is  it possible to automatically filetrout node-ids that has a specific tag via osmx.jl package or OSMnx?
I've tried to use xml parsing, howver, it return some sort of `not well-formed` error for some lines. But when I look at those lines , they are perfectly valid. For instance, the following line

```
 <node id="2826472874" visible="true" version="1" changeset="22043570" timestamp="2014-04-30T13:38:20Z" user="Rub21_nycbuildings" uid="1781294" lat="40.7132669" lon="-73.9967686"/>
```

cause an error of `(invalid token): line 8228, column 2` when I try to pars the data via ElementTree. What is the issue?

Is it possible to directly identify nodes with specific tags (like "id="3774690783"" for "railway" in   `<tag k="railway" v="subway_entrance"/>`, and store them into a dict, list,..

Comment: You really really should parse the file as XML, and to do that you'll need to figure out what's wrong with the file or the XML parser.

Comment: Try osmfiletr and once the data is filtered than import it to Julia. This is much faster and much easier, see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter     Perhaps looking on another code I am working too might help as well: https://github.com/mkloe/OSMgetPOI.jl

Comment: It is possible that the file is not well-formed but the package struggle to pinpoint to the correct location. Maybe the issue is on the previous block.
You can check that with an online XML validator

Comment: @Thomas Jalabert the part that don't understand is that when I shutdown the kernel and run the cell al over again the line it points to changes! ans there's no problem with that line at all. I also tried to check the file for the corrctness of the encoding via chardet, and it shows `ascii` which is valid

Comment: @Przemyslaw Szufel thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a try. But julia can combine this filtered info to existing ones? I mean I have a map already imported and need to find IDs inside it with specific tages. So, if I select the same boundary on osmfilter, the id and info shoud work togethere hopefully?

Comment: You can always search for nearest nodes having latitude and longitude  so it is always somehow possible to match one map data with other. Additionally, nodeids is OSM files are standardized and globally unique.